# Copying an audiobook by chapter to play somewhere else

Tags: itunes

I purchased an audiobook from Audible and downloaded it to my iTunes account. I'm a teacher and with distance learning, I need to post certain chapters on Google Classroom for the kids to listen to the book. How do I do that? I see that the book is broken into chapters, but I can't see how to copy them into a different file that I could upload to Classroom. I'm on a MacBook Air 10.14.6 running Mojave.

Comment: Did you purchase an education license from Audible or the publisher that allows you to do this legally. Because, as it is described, this might be considered piracy.

Comment: Get the students to purchase the audiobook themselves. Or check with your library - they may have a solution.

Comment: Teachers used to be able to buy a cd of a book and play it in the classroom. They don't make book cd's anymore, which is why I purchase on Audible. I can't ask families to pay $20 per copy of the book, that's insanely expensive!